# dynamo db query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have my dynamo db table as follows:

```
HashKey(xyz) ,RangeKey(timestamp)
```

Now for each hash key i have set of range key.

Now i want to query based on set of hashkey and i want only most recent value correspoding to that to be fetched .I dont want to do in memory sorting and then picking most recent version.

Can i do this in  any way?

Use case is that i will do a bulkget and pass set of hashkey (say 100) , so i want to get one record for each hashkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (currently) can't set constraints on a batch get. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_BatchGetItems.html

However, for single hash keys, you can set the direction using ScanIndexForward. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Query.html for information.

Sample java code:

```
new QueryRequest().withTableName("table-name")
  .withScanIndexForward(false)
  .withLimit(1)
  .withHashKeyValue(new AttributeValue().withS("hash-key"));
```

It will not be very efficient though, as you will need to make this call 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use ScanIndexForward(true for ascending and false for descending) and can also limit the result using setLimit value of Query Expression.

Please find below the code where used QueryPage for finding the single record.

public EventLogEntitySave fetchLatestEvents(String id) {
    EventLogEntitySave entity = new EventLogEntitySave();
    entity.setId(id);

    DynamoDBQueryExpression<EventLogEntitySave> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<EventLogEntitySave>().withHashKeyValues(entity);
    queryExpression.setScanIndexForward(false);
    queryExpression.withLimit(1);
    queryExpression.setLimit(1);

    List<EventLogEntitySave> result = dynamoDBMapper.queryPage(EventLogEntitySave.class, queryExpression).getResults();
    System.out.println("size of records = "+result.size() );
    result.get(0);
}

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "PROD_EA_Test")
public class EventLogEntitySave {

        @DynamoDBHashKey
        private String id;
        private String reconciliationProcessId;
        private String vin;
        private String source;
}

public class DynamoDBConfig {
    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {

            String accesskey = "";
            String secretkey = "";
            //
            // creating dynamo client
            BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accesskey, secretkey);
            AmazonDynamoDB dynamo = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
            dynamo.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
            return dynamo;
        }
```

Comment: id is the hashkey and timestamp is the sort key, fetchLatestEvents returning latest function based on id, if scanIndexForward value is marked true then will return the oldest event and with value false will return the recent event, and sorting is not happening in memory instead